# How do I use df.iloc[] slices to pull and merge 2 different slices of columns in a DF and set to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy

**Im trying to slice out 2 arrays of columns and have them displayed together represented by a variable.**

It is important that I use **.iloc** because the DF being used can change each time, as can the number of columns and names, but The first 3 and last 3 column headers dont change no matter the DF.

Everything I can find shows me how to do this using the headers, but I cannot do that.

**Below Im trying to tell it to "Pull all rows in columns 1 through 3, and columns 6 through two less than the last one"**

Im having a really hard time converting that sentence above into the proper syntax in Python. I especially need the part where I include everything up to 2 columns less than the last one because each dataframe that gets loaded into this can have different numbers of columns.

It wont event let me put 2 ranges together even if I dont have the "-2"

```
month = input("What month are you drawing for? ")

year = input("What year are you drawing for? ")

import pandas
ticket_entries = pandas.read_csv(month+year+'.csv')

event1 = ticket_entries.iloc[:,[1:3,6:(-2)]].copy()

event1
```

> invalid sytax

Comment: `ticket_entries.iloc[:,np.r_[1:3,6-df.shape[1]:(-2)]].copy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy `.r_` function which translates slice objects to list

```
import numpy as np
event1 = ticket_entries.iloc[:,np.r_[1:3,6:-2]].copy()
```